# search result won't automatically display

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have building a Giphy Gif search app through giphy API and it works fine just each time when i tried to type something new in the search text and the new search result won't pop out unless i reload the page.

the HTML code as following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Giphy Search App</title>


    <style>
.container-image {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right:3%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container container-padding50">
        <input type="text" class="js-userinput container-textinput" placeholder="refresh the page if you wanna searching more">

        <button class="js-go container-button">Go!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="js-container">          
    </div>
    <script src ="javascript/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

the js code in `main.js`file as:

```
document.querySelector(".js-go").addEventListener("click",function(e){
var input = document.querySelector("input").value;
searchGiphy(input);
});
document.querySelector(".js-userinput").addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
var input = document.querySelector("input").value;
if(e.which == 13){
    searchGiphy(input);     
}
});
function searchGiphy(searchResult){

var  url = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&q=" + searchResult;
var GiphyAJAXCall = new XMLHttpRequest();
    GiphyAJAXCall.open("GET",url);
    GiphyAJAXCall.send();

    GiphyAJAXCall.addEventListener("load",function(e){
        var data = e.target.response;
        pushToDOM(data);
    });
}
function pushToDOM(input){
var response = JSON.parse(input);

var imageUrls = response.data;
var container = document.querySelector(".js-container");

imageUrls.forEach(function(image){

var src = image.images.fixed_height.url;
container.innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + src + "\" class=\"container-image\">";

  });
}
```

I am pasting all the js code above and wondering am i wrong with the ajax calling here? Could some one help me with this?

Comment: The code works fine for me.

Comment: I mean each time when I am typing something new I the search text the result won't automatically pops up

Comment: How can I make that happen with just a simple click "go"button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the results to the end of the current html instead of replacing what is already there. Instead use another variable to build the new html string you are constructing and then when you are done replace the innerHTML of the container with the new string.

```
function pushToDOM(input){
var response = JSON.parse(input);
var imageUrls = response.data;
var container = document.querySelector(".js-container");
var html = "";

imageUrls.forEach(function(image){
    var src = image.images.fixed_height.url;
    html += "<img src=\"" + src + "\" class=\"container-image\">";
});
container.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works for me, so there is no problem with my ajax here right? only the innerHTML.

Comment: I didn't see any problems with it.